# Asp.net MVC 5, Html.Checkbox on click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I'm building an interface that adds events to a calendar depending on which checkboxes are checked. Currently I can get the event to fire like so:

```
@Html.CheckBox("Mon1D", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

And the JS:

```
    $('#Mon1D').click(function () {
               //some code
    });
```

Great right? Wrong. If I take this approach, I'll have to make a (nearly) identical function for all 42 checkboxes. I'd much rather make a one-size fits all function to handle onclick events for the checkboxes. I'm a bit of a javascript noob though, so I can't quite figure out why my onclick isn't firing.

The onclick looks like this:

```
        $myFunction(function () {
             //some code
    });
```

And the checkbox

```
@Html.CheckBox("Mon1D", new { htmlAttributes = new { @onclick = "myFunction()", @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Do you have multiple checkboxes? If your using `@Html.CheckBox("Mon1D", ...)` for all of them, your generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. Give them a class name and use `$('.yourclassname').click(function () { if ($(this).is(':checked')) { ...`

Comment: They all have different IDs. Mon1D, Mon1E, Mon1N, Tue1D... etc.

Comment: That's OK then, but just use a class name as a selector - `@Html.CheckBox("Mon1D", new { @class = "form-control check-box" })`

Comment: How is the reaction different based on check box? Only difference is the event ID?

Comment: Event Id, and date should be the only two that matter. But each checkbox will have a different date associated (it's not built like that yet).

Comment: Oh and title will change depending on selection as well.

Comment: You have not explained in your question what your trying to do (both scripts have identical code). If you want to pass the something to the script, then `@Html.CheckBox("Mon1D", new { @class = "form-control check-box", data_eventid = someValue })` and access it using `var eventID = $(this).data('eventid');`

Comment: Still not clear what data you want to pass to the script, but the easiest way is to use `data-*` attributes in the checkbox element.

Comment: well if I can get 'onclick' to work, I can pass parameters there, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem here: 'onclick' wasn't firing because it was INSIDE the 'htmlattributes' class. It needs to be defined anonymously. Like so:

```
@Html.CheckBox("someID", new { @onclick = "myFunction();", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

EDIT: Adding the HTML result of the above code.

```
<input htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="someID" name="someID" onclick="myFunction();" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

Comment: What? Have you checked the html that generates - it cannot possibly work correctly, and sure wont add `class = "form-control"` to your element (but it will add an invalid  `htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }` attribute

Comment: And stop polluting your mark up with behavior - its the 21st century - use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: It does work. Thanks for the advice on my JS, but I'm not a frontend developer, and this is the one frontend thing that my application needs to do. 

I will definitely consider your advice if I end up working on something with more frontend functionality.

Comment: As far as your comment that it can't possibly work, well, it does. I'll edit with the HTML the above code generates.

Comment: I think I can be fairly confident in guessing say that you wanted to add a class name (`form-control`) to your input. It generates `htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }"` which is not only an invalid attribute,the class name is missing i.e. it does not work :)

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. The code you're talking about is generated by the MVC 5 scaffolding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137697/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-scuba-steve).

Comment: Sorry Stephen, missed your chat invite yesterday.

Comment: Did you see the comment I added there?

Answer (score 0):

> If I take this approach, I'll have to make a (nearly) identical function for all 42 checkboxes.

Take a different approach. jQuery has another selector that allows selecting by class like this:

```
$('.form-control').click(function (event) {
     // to get the element that fired the event
     alert(event.target.id);
     // or you can use the 'this' variable like below
     var $element = $(this);
     // And then you can get any attribute of the element like this
     var id = $element.attr('id');
     var someOtherAttribute = $element.attr('whateverYouNeed');
});
```

`this` refers to the element which fired the event. Using `$(this)` will wrap it as a jQuery object and then you can use all the jQuery available calls on it.

Any element, which has class `form-control`, its `click` event will be intercepted by that.

Comment: @scubasteve did this help or you are still having difficulty?

Comment: Just sat down to work, I'll code this up and let you know.

Comment: If I wanted to pass a value on-click, how would I go about that?

Comment: Or even, without passing anything, how do I go about getting at the element that fired the event?